# Mock the suspendCoroutine interface return callback

Tags: android, mockito, mockk

I am trying to mock the below method: service and raspExecuteConfig is injected in constructor and is mocked.
setDomTimeis the method in library which accept the int, object and interface.
Interface act as callback with Bool and INT values.

How can i mock the service.setDomTime method , so that i can return the mocked interface callback.

```
private suspend fun setTime(): Boolean {
            suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
                service.setDomTime(
                    Date().time,
                    raspExecuteConfig
                ) { setTimeBool, anyInt ->
                    continuation.resume(setClock)
                }
            }
    }
```

I tried using MOCKK:

```
val interf = mockk<IRaspResponse<Boolean>>()
            coEvery {
                mockservice.setDomTime(
                    anyInt(),
                    raspExecuteConfig,
                    interf
                )
            } returns
                interf.onResponse(
                    false,
                   12345
                )
```

But get the error  Invalid use of argument matchers

Comment: I think someone has already solved this problem. Please check the below link https://kotlintesting.com/mocking-suspend-with-mockk/

Answer (score 0):

Mockito requires you to either use only raw values or only matchers when stubbing a method call.

So when you use anyInt(), you need to replace raspExecuteConfig and interf with argument matchers too. Also you can remove anyInt() and pass int variable